# Using a selection sort on an ArrayList of Strings

Tags: java, sorting

I have a program that is counting the frequencies of words taken from a txt file and they are being stored in an ArrayList. I am extremely unfamiliar with using a selection sort but it is the type of sort that I am being asked to use. I have looked at multiple selection sorts, but mine is falling short somewhere along the line.

This is my actual sort.

```
private void sort() {

    for (int i = 0; i < wordArray.size() - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < wordArray.size(); j++) {
            if (wordArray.get(i).compareTo(wordArray.get(j)) == 1) {

                Word temp = wordArray.get(i);
                wordArray.set(i, wordArray.get(j));
                wordArray.set(j, temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my comparison of strings (I am pretty sure the logic error is in here).

```
public int compareTo(Word w) {

    for (int i = 0; i < this.word.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (i <= w.word.length() - 1) {
            if (this.word.charAt(i) < w.word.charAt(i)) {
                return -1;
            } else if (this.word.charAt(i) > w.word.charAt(i)){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Word is a class that has the String variable "word". Any tips would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What is going wrong with this?  i.e. what is the incorrect behaviour?  Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: above, add, a, advanced, ago, all, as, altogether, and, any, are, be.      This is a sample of how it is currently turning out. The document has about 138 unique words in it.

Comment: I don't think you want to implement the sort on your own.  I also believe that the Word.compareTo can simply delegate to the Word's String.compareTo.

Comment: If you are suspicious that your `compareTo` method is broken, why not try testing it in isolation?

Comment: @ditkin That is why I am having a hard time finding useful information from Google, but I am explicitly told to manually use the selection sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use this

```
public int compareTo(Word w) {
    return this.word.compareTo(w.word);
}
```

Comment: Actually after changing the compareTo AND my sort to     if (wordArray.get(i).compareTo(wordArray.get(j)) >=1)    It works :) Thank you!